# wso2 identity server - APIs

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, identity

From reading on [WSO2 Identity Server](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/),
it mentions about an API for integration to other applications.

Is this API documented ? I have not been able to the find WSO2 Identity Server API documentation.

My requirement is to integrate - a couple of Ruby/Rails and PHP applications and provide Identity management and Single Sign solution across these. Can this requirement be met with WSO2 Identity Server ?

Thanks

Comment: http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2012/11/wso2-identity-server-as-scim-service.html

Comment: The above link provides some useful insights.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve SSO capabilities of Identity Server,  there are few ways...

1. [SAML2 SSO Web browser based SSO](https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Configuring+SAML2+SSO)
2. [OpenID](http://pathberiya.blogspot.com/2010/08/sign-up-with-openid-providered-by.html)
3. [Passive STS](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/12/configuring-wso2-identity-server-passive-sts-aspnet-client/)

Also,  there are user management API that has been exposed as web service API and SCIM.